# Excel, large number copying error

Tags: excel, copy

I've got a problem when I'm trying to paste data into excel. I'm downloading data in excel sheet, but in some cells there are numbers of length of 22 digits so excel converts them to scientific notation and after changing the format to text only 15 first digits are correct and else are zeros, Is there any way to convert the numbers from that scientific notation back into exact number. In my opinion no, but maybe there is some way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [You cannot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel): "Although Excel can display 30 decimal places, its precision for a specified number is confined to 15 significant figures" If you don't intend to perform any calculation on the number, it would be better to import the column containing the numbers as text instead.

Comment: well yes, but the problem is that I'm downloading data already converted into scientific notation and I cant download it in text format.

Comment: If you are downloading the numbers in a scientific notation there is no possible way to convert them back to the real number. The scientific notatiton simply loses the precision and gives `0` at the end.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking. Thanks for help :)

Comment: If the downloaded data is *already converted into scientific notation*, how would you know that it is 22 digits long?  Is it being exported from the source as an Excel file?  If so, you need to have it exported as a csv or txt file, and not as an Excel file.  There is something about your process of getting the data from the source and into Excel that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Hi, I know that this number has 22 digits, because it's some reference number that contains 22 digits. It's downloading from data base and is already uploaded in excel format to the site where I'm downloading it from. I need to check if I can export it as csv or txt. If there will be already shortened numbers the only way I can see is to download it as txt from data base and then copy to excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the range of excel as Text, before writing the number there. Then it will be ok. But you will not be able to make any formula calculations:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim largeNumber     As String
    largeNumberic = largeNumber

    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = largeNumber

End Sub
```